# How can I see the inner product of two wedge products as a determinant?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I want to show that

$\langle u \wedge v, x\wedge y\rangle = det\begin{bmatrix}\langle u,x\rangle&\langle v,x\rangle\\\langle u,y\rangle&\langle v,y\rangle \end{bmatrix}$

from the properties of the wedge product, but I don't know how to get from the left to the right side at all, because the properties don't really give me a way to "get rid of the $\wedge$", if that makes sense. I know that in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the cross product satisfies all properties of the wedge product, so we can identify the wedge product with the cross product and then I get this result through simple calculation, but this is not what I want to do and you also can't use this in higher dimensions.

Comment: Isn’t this just the definition of the inner product on the exterior algebra?

Comment: I'm reading Do Carmo's book and he apparently proves this, saying it is a straightforward verification which I don't understand. We derived the wedge product a bit more formally than him but end up with the same standard properties of the wedge product. So I thought it was possible to use them to get this result.

Comment: I might have a solution. In our lecture we derived a mapping $\Phi_0: \bigwedge^k V^*\rightarrow A^k(V)$ from the exterior power of the dual space to the space of multilinear alternating forms as the determinant of a matrix. And fixing one argument in the inner product makes it become an element of $V^*$. So fixing the left and right side respectively gives me what i was looking for right?

Comment: How does he prove it? It is important to give his definition as part of your post/question. I imagine I know the answer, but I cannot be a mind-reader. In answer to your comment questions, no, none of that addresses the definition of the inner product on the vector space $\bigwedge^2 V$.

Comment: We defined the exterior power as a quotient space so we only really get that $\wedge$ is alternating and multilinear from which we can derive other properties (which Do Carmo just gives as properties since he doesn't formally derive the wedge product).

Comment: And you are correct, using what I said above I can't formally "derive" the inner product, it just coincidentally had the same result. Maybe I'm also just trying to derive something that is just a definition here, but both Do Carmo's Book and our lecture did not define the inner product so I thought there would be some way to derive it or at least some intuition behind it.

Comment: The definitions Do Carmo uses are given here: https://fedika.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Differential-Geometry-of-Curves-Surfaces.pdf on page 13 and 14. Since the book takes place in an $\mathbb{R}^3$ setting, for him wedge product and cross product are the same.

Comment: Do Carmo's proof is straightforward. Indeed, all of the vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $u\wedge v$ is simply the cross product and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the dot product. As he says, it is easy to see that each side of the equation is, if you fix any 3 of the vectors, a linear function of the 4th. Therefore, it suffices to show that the equation holds when the vectors are all basis vecvtors. You can do that by simply working out every possibility. By the symmetry of the dot product and the antisymmetry of the cross (wedge) product, there are only 3 possilibites to check.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understood it from this.